# Sorting in C# Report rdlc

Tags: c#-4.0, reporting

I made a report which contain a table that contain DatabaseView of 3 databases tables like that:

```
   table name
datbase1 row1
database2 row1
database3 row1
```

the problem is database 2 have more than one row and the report repeat all the table instead of push the database 2 rows in the middle.
I want to show the table like this:

```
   table name
datbase1 row1
database2 row1
          row2
          row3 ..
database3 row1
```

Using VS2010 , C# , Windows Form.
Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a case of `Grouping` and not of `Sorting`.

To accomplish your needs you have to creare a Row Group based on your `table` value: this will not replicate the value of table.

The expected output will be something like this

```
+----------------+
|Table    | Name |
|----------------|
|database1| row1 |
|---------|------|
|database2| row1 |
|         |------|
|         | row2 |
|         |------|
|         | row3 |
|---------|------|
|database3| row1 |
+----------------+
```

[MSDN Library's How to Grouping Data in Report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251700%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for help but when I grouped every database I got every database duplicate its row like this : database1 row1 ,row1 ,row1 and database2 row2,row2,row2... like this

Comment: If `database1` got only one row, I don't see how `row1` is replicated. Maybe you are doing soethign wrong. Check these othere 2 link: [link1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240753.aspx) and [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e3d61228-2aa4-42cc-955e-602dbf3406a7)

Comment: you're welcome! Remember to check my answer by clicking the big "check" icon in the left of my post!